# Importance of QUANT score on GRE for math grad school

Tags: graduate-admissions, mathematics, united-states

I am not the best at standardized test taking and scored a very poor score of quant 153 on the GRE. I go to a good undergrad institution with no grade inflation (Purdue university). My grades, especially in upper level math classes, are good (A's in Real Analysis, ODE, Vector Calc, Statistical Analysis, A- in PDE). Though I did get a B- in Linear algebra and a B in Probability. I have a cumulative GPA of 3.72 with a major GPA of 3.6. Would I still be able to get into a Group 2 program with my current marks?

I am registering for the Math Subject, and oddly I feel much more confident with the types of questions asked compared to the regular GRE. Would a strong math subject GRE cover up the blemish of my GRE score?

Comment: Is this question USA-specific?

Comment: @TommiBrander Yes

Comment: I added the corresponding tag.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, at least, no single thing is likely to knock you out of contention. Aim high, but don't put all of your eggs into too few baskets. The competition is fierce, of course, in top level schools, but if you put together a good application that clearly predicts success you should come out well. But, make sure that you have very strong letters of recommendation from people who can speak both of your past success and your likelihood of future "wins". How hard you work, how serious you are, etc.

I suppose there are a few places that might have a cut-off score, but not everywhere you might want to go would do that. It is rather foolish in any case.